# Facebook Notification Handler with iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios7, ios8

I have little Confusion regarding my iPhone application. So I hope I got solution from here.

Now My Question is:

Currently I am developing an iPhone application with Facebook user integration. User can send application request to his/her friend as a Facebook notification. If receiver accept that request or click on that request then how should I detect that through my iPhone application? Or is there any way to show that notification in my iPhone application?(Functionality is like get Life by Friends in Candy Crush Game)

Some Points

---

- I have created canvas for application integration with Facebook but there is no any kind of functionality on my application's canvas page. It is totally blank. I just want application on iPhone not on Facebook.
- On every click on app invitation notification by receiver I want to give some points to notification sender.

If you have any king of link or document related to this topic then please send me.